# javascript Text to Speech arabic

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-to-speech

I'm trying to make `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` work for Arabic

It's working fine for English

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var u1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world!');
  u1.lang = 'en-US';
  u1.pitch = 20;
  u1.rate = 1;
  u1.voiceURI = 'native';
  u1.volume = 1000;
  speechSynthesis.speak(u1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

But when Arabic is used

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var u1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('عربي');
  u1.lang = 'ar-AE';
  u1.pitch = 20;
  u1.rate = 1;
  u1.voiceURI = 'native';
  u1.volume = 1000;
  speechSynthesis.speak(u1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Arabic works for me in Chrome for Linux Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: i try opera browser not work 

$(document).ready(function () {
 debugger;
 var u1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('رقم 15');
 u1.lang = 'ar-AE';
 u1.pitch = 20;
 u1.rate = 1;
 //u1.voice = voices[10];
 u1.voiceURI = 'native';
 u1.volume = 1;
 speechSynthesis.speak(u1);

Comment: @user3515102: this is a great opportunity to switch to a better OS... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` function doesn't support Arabic, and [only supports the following languages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices#JavaScript) with their respective voices :

```js
speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
  var voices = this.getVoices();
  console.log(voices);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
    <script>
        function speakArabic() {
            const textToSpeak = document.getElementById("arabicText").value;
            responsiveVoice.speak(textToSpeak, "Arabic Male");
        }
        function stopReading() {
            responsiveVoice.cancel();
        }
        function speakEnglish() {
            const textToSpeak =
                document.getElementById("englishText").value;
            responsiveVoice.speak(textToSpeak, "US English Female");
        }
        function speakIndonesian() {
            const textToSpeak =
                document.getElementById("indonesianText").value;
            responsiveVoice.speak(textToSpeak, "Indonesian Male");
        }
        function startReading(lang) {
            let text;
            if (lang === "en-US") {
                speakEnglish();
            } else if (lang === "id-ID") {
                speakIndonesian();
            }
        }
        function stopReading(lang) {
            responsiveVoice.cancel();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I use text-to-speech codes for Arabic (also English and Indonesian) as written above.

Comment: To make this work you will need to ensure that Arabic TTS is available on the target device. So on a Windows machine, Windows need to have it installed. This is part of the difficulty with make this solution work. But the results are very good.