# How do I access a text to speech voice when I make a website ( for Edge browser)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, text-to-speech

When I run load the webpage below in Edge it tells me that 8 voices are available on my computer. But only 2 are operational voice[4] and voice[7]. In firefox there is only one available and operational, voice[0].

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<title>Speech synthesiser</title>

<script>

var synth = window.speechSynthesis;


function populateVoiceList() {

var voiceSelect = document.getElementById("voicesAvailable");

        voiceSelect.innerHTML = '';

    voices = synth.getVoices();

    for(i = 0; i < voices.length ; i++) {

        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.textContent = voices[i].name + ' (' + voices[i].lang + ')';

        voiceSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="populateVoiceList()">

<h1>speech test 1</h1>

<form id="myForm">

  <select id="voicesAvailable">
    <option>Choose a voice</option>
  </select>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

In Microsoft Edge browser there seems to be a geographic filter being applied to restrict the voices. So, while 8 names get placed in the drop-down box only 2 actually are available.  How do I modify the program so that I only load the voices which will work on the computer?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

New Edit..

I found a related question containing a [response from Islam Elshobokosy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591655/367865). He submitted this code snippet:

```
speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
  var voices = this.getVoices();
  console.log(voices);
};
```

When I clicked the associated button on the Stack Overflow page to run that code it produced a result that revealed the only two functioning voices on my computer. It did not give the other 6.

My question is now: 
1. How is this code filtering out the 6 irrelevant voices that my webpage page (above) is finding? 
2. How do I incorporate something like this into my webpage?

Comment: Provide the link to the question/answer you're referring to.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: it was in the question  " javascript Text to Speech Arabic "

Comment: Thanks for making the link, Ouroborus. When I run that snippet I get exactly the result I want. But I do not know how to generate it in my webpage. Is something in the Stack Overflow wrapping code acting as a filter?

Comment: Seems some browsers do not have a valid list until the`voiceschanged` event fires while others do have a valid list on ready and don't fire an initial `voiceschanges` so you have to take both situations into account. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/onvoiceschanged#Examples

Comment: thanks for your input Ouroborus. I have taken the if-statements from the link and put them in the webpage code. It doesn't seem to matter where I put them, I keep getting 8 available languages in Edge. To be honest I am now quite confused.

Comment: when  I add this code to the function all languages appear as local.

Comment: if(voices[i].localService == true ) {
        option.textContent += ' -- local';
     }

Comment: When I ran this webpage on a different computer running the same version of Edge it worked , giving 2 voices. ??????